# Certification SSl with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a spring jsf application and I'd like to secure with SSL certification for that I created a sll certification with
`keytool -genkey -alias monserveur -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\security\monfichier.keystore`

And I made the necessary configuration tomcat but when acees via https he told me that the ssl certifiacation is not certified.
Have you an idea about this problem and how to make the ssl certification certified?

Comment: You're using a self-signed certificate, which aren't recognized by your browser/machine as being verifiable through a Certificate Authority. To have a valid certificate You need to either get a certificate from a valid CA (godaddy, verisign, etc..) or import the certificate as valid to each machine that will hit your site.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have created a self signed certificate.  To get most browsers to trust your certificate, you need to get it signed by a certificate signing authority (CA).  This involves first generating a certificate signing request, then paying a CA to sign it, and installing the signed certificates from the CA in your keystore.

More on generating a certificate signing request here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggezu/index.html

If you google for "certificate signing", you'll see plenty of ads from CAs happy to take your money to sign your certificate.

Comment: i flow the oracle tutorial but i get this error have you any idea to resolve this idea : 
Error opening CA Certificate ca-certificate.pem.txt
6532:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio\
bss_file.c:398:fopen('ca-certificate.pem.txt','rb')